# Nodes in Domino Tree

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, graph-algorithm

Suppose you have a double n domino. Take one piece and choose one of its sides. With that side as root, draw the tree with all the posible combinations of pieces sharing that side. The pieces with the same value in each side count as only one subtree. 
See this [Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUI9N.jpg) for an example of tree with a double 2 domino, with [0,1] as root and 0 as the chosen side.

This tree contains 14 nodes. 
Now iterate on each piece as root and each side as chosen side.

The question is, what is the maximum number of nodes in those trees?
I created a program and I have some information.

```
Double N          Maximum Nodes in some tree
      0                          1
      1                          3
      2                          21
      3                          487
      4                          147753
      5                          133720011
```

I dont know if there is formula, algorithm, pseudocode, dynamic programing to solve this problem, but any help is welcome.

EDIT:
Is is not difficult to see that all the pieces with the same value in both sides induced a tree with the same number of nodes, and the same holds for all the pieces with different value, due permutations. 
So, you only need check the number of nodes in the tree with the [0 0] piece as root.

Comment: What are configurations for 3 and 21? I cannot imagine size 3 tree from 0/0, 0/1, 1/1 pieces.

Comment: I dont understand your question. You can put the pieces 0/0->0/1->1/1 and you get a tree with 3 nodes. But if you start with these piece 0/1->1/1 you can only build a tree with 2 nodes, but the maximum is 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be related to counting paths in a complete graph that don't use the same edge twice. You can consider a complete graph on vertices labeled `0` through `N`, and each domino can be thought of as an edge between the numbers on it. Note that you are also including an edge from each vertex to itself.

A related and probably easier problem is that of counting *Eulerian* paths, i.e. using every single domino. There does not seem to be a completely closed form answer even for that, but here is a paper that analyzes it and gives some calculations: http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/euler.pdf.